# Datasets for demonstrating data/model/concept drift

Tags: dataset, concept-drift, data-drift

Are there any well-known datasets that are useful for illustrating the concept of data and/or model/concept drift?  I can create my own out of, say, MNIST (by e.g. removing digits and adding them in later), but would like to know if there's anything on (say) Kaggle that is best suited for that purpose.  Thank you!